# Writing 100GB data in S3 taking 7 long hours - Speed optimization

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

[Spark UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgm78.png)I am running spark job on emr cluster with below configuration

I have total 14 s3 objects to read I am doing all left joins on them -**persisting input data**:

```
df1 = spark.read.parquet("\file1").select(required columns).distinct() --173063 records
df1.persist()
df2 = spark.read.parquet("\file2").select(required columns).distinct() --140424 records
df2.persist()
df3 = spark.read.parquet("\file3").select(required columns).distinct() --4255 records
df3.persist()
df4 = spark.read.parquet("\file4").select(required columns).distinct() --475750 records
df4.persist()
df5 = spark.read.parquet("\file5").select(required columns).distinct() --95778 records
df5.persist()
df6 = spark.read.parquet("\file6").select(required columns).distinct() --63464 records
df6.persist()
df7 = spark.read.parquet("\file7").select(required columns).distinct() --2250 records
df7.persist()
df8 = spark.read.parquet("\file8").select(required columns).distinct() --360 records
df8.persist()
df9 = spark.read.parquet("\file9").select(required columns).distinct() --202297 records
df9.persist()
df10 = spark.read.parquet("\file110").select(required columns).distinct() --134573 records
df10.persist()
df11 = spark.read.parquet("\file11").select(required columns).distinct() --125541 records
df11.persist()
df12 = spark.read.parquet("\file12").select(required columns).distinct() --202 records
df12.persist()
df13 = spark.read.parquet("\file13").select(required columns).distinct() --207 records
df13.persist()
df14 = spark.read.parquet("\file14").select(required columns).distinct() --21124 records
df14.persist()
```

Now I am joining each df one by one all are **broadcast joins and left joins**

**dropping not-required columns after each join**

**Persisting intermediate results of joins**

```
join1_df = df1.join(broadcast(df2),left).drop(not required columns used in join)
join1_df.persist()
join2_df = join1_df.join(broadcast(df3),left).drop(not required columns used in join)
join2_df.persist()
join3_df = join2_df.join(broadcast(df4),left).drop(not required columns used in join)
join3_df.persist()
join4_df = join3_df.join(broadcast(df5),left).drop(not required columns used in join)
join4_df.persist()
join5_df = join4_df.join(broadcast(df6),left).drop(not required columns used in join)
join5_df.persist()
join6_df = join5_Df.join(broadcast(df7),left).drop(not required columns used in join)
join6_df.persist()
join7_df = join5_Df.join(broadcast(df8),left).drop(not required columns used in join)
join7_df.persist()
join8_df = join5_Df.join(broadcast(df9),left).drop(not required columns used in join)
join8_df.persist()
join9_df = join5_Df.join(broadcast(df10),left).drop(not required columns used in join)
join9_df.persist()
join10_df = join5_Df.join(broadcast(df11),left).drop(not required columns used in join)
join10_df.persist()
join11_df = join5_Df.join(broadcast(df12),left).drop(not required columns used in join)
join11_df.persist()
join12_df = join5_Df.join(broadcast(df13),left).drop(not required columns used in join)
join12_df.persist()

final_df = join5_Df.join(broadcast(df14),left).drop(not required columns used in join)
final_df.persist()
```

**final dataframe has 56 columns to write in parquet format:**

```
final_df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(s3 location)
```

final_df size is **109GB**

write step took **7 hours** to s3 after that I checked s3 location where
**201** files are created each file size is almost **570 MB** and total size is **109GB**. Created athena table on top of this
**Total record count : 8471166455**
**Cluster info :**

```
aws.emr.instance_type: "r5.12xlarge"
aws.emr.no_of_instances: "40"
```

**Coming to spark configuration**

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode client --master yarn 
--conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true 
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true 
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors=5 
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=5 
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=40 
--conf spark.executor.cores=10 
--conf spark.executor.memory=150G 
--conf spark.driver.memory=150G 
--conf \"spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UseG1GC\" 
--conf \"spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UseG1GC\"
```

Please help to understand correct spark configuration if incase that is the problem.

tried broadcast joins
persist intermediate results
increase spark configurations - num of executors, driver memory and executor memory
drop not-required columns after each join

Comment: you don't need to broadcast each and every dataframe. e.g. df1 and df2 have similar number of rows, and assuming they have same columns, you shouldn't broadcast df2. only broadcast the smaller of the 2 dataframes (and the smaller has to be considerably smaller than the other)

Comment: thanks I will update my code accordingly. any changes required in spark configuration?

Comment: i'm not an expert in that *and I always say configs are best with hit-and-trials*, but I don't think you'd need a 150G driver.

Comment: these persists are unnecessary and could effect on your performance

Comment: code with no persists was taking more than 7 hours to write files!!!

Comment: Indiscriminate persisting of dataframes that are not being reused anywhere, along with all the distincts and dropping unneeded columns too late, would be definitely detrimental. Having 10 cores per executor (=10 tasks inside a single JVM) probably saturates disk and network IO as well.

Comment: Also, have a look at your [Spark UI](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/web-ui.html) or write your event logs to a [History Server](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#viewing-after-the-fact). This will allow you to understand which stages are taking a long time. I suspect that with your amount of joins your query plan will be quite large, so you'll be able to indentify some interesting bottlenecks.

Comment: @mazaneicha I am taking distinct while reading data and before joining 14 tables itself to avoid join on duplicate records unnecessarily . I am dropping columns after join because at the time of join I need them but not needed in my final output so as soon as I perform join I am dropping them making sure that they aren't needed in my final output.

Comment: @Koedlt if you could  find attachments of my spark UI for recent run. by the way I did some hit and try on spark configuration: --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors=5 --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=5 --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=40 --conf spark.default.parallelism=150 --conf spark.executor.cores=10 --conf spark.executor.memory=150G --conf spark.driver.memory=150G --conf \"spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UseG1GC\" --conf \"spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UseG1GC\"

Comment: above configuration did not work job ran for 12 hours and failed

Comment: @Koedlt I have added spark UI image at beginning of my question. It is space issue , but I am trying to understand what should be the exact spark configuration to avoid this space issue. df.write.mode(overwrite).parquet(s3 location) this step is taking longer time . and this final df has 109GB data